# How can I move pagination of a DataTable to the top?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have tried these

```
"sDom": '<"top"<"actions">fpi<"clear">><"clear">rt<"bottom">',
"sDom": '<"top"p><"bottom"top><"clear">',
"sDom": '<"top"<"actions">fpil<"clear">><"clear">rt<"bottom">',
```

But it does not work, the pagination bar still on the bottom (like default)
My dataTable does not have fiter, info, length ..., just data and pagination.

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sDom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">'

Comment: I want to move pagination bar to a specific position? how can I do?

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack Overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.